# Setting infoWindow for a list of markers created inside a callback function (directionsService)

Tags: javascript, callback, google-maps-api-3, closures

I'm trying to set infoWindows for markers that are created in the callback function of a directionsService (Google Maps API V3). I tried many different ways to do that without any luck..

Here is a skeleton of how my code looks like:

```
for(i=0;i<markersList.length;i++){
map = someMap
var request = myRequestObject;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

directionsService.route(request, (function (address) {
  return function(response, status) {
    //Use the directions service to do some stuff
    //..Then create markers
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                       map: map,
                       title: address['title']
                   });
    //push the marker to a list of markers attached to the map
    //this can be useful to delete all markers in a later step
    map.markers.push(marker);

    //Creating multiple instances of infoWindows works fine though..
    //However, Creating 1 info window for the whole map doesn't work from here
    //If I try that, I'd set the same content for all info windows
    //which is not what I want.
  }
 }
)(markersList[i])
);

}
```

I tried doing this, which didn't work either:

```
//add setInfo as a custom function to my map
//then call it to iterate over all markers and add info windows
google.maps.Map.prototype.setInfo = function() {

   for(var i=0; i < this.markers.length; i++){
        infowindow.setContent(this.markers[i].getTitle());
        google.maps.event.addListener(this.markers[i], 'click', function(){
            infowindow.close();
            infowindow.open(map,this.markers[i]);
            });
    }
};
```

Then I'd call this function after I'm done with directionsService.route (check the first code block), outside my main for-loop. However, it never finds any markers attached to the map for some reason..

Any thoughts on how to assign the right infoWindows to the map markers?
I want to have 1 infoWindow instance so that I could close it when a new infoWindow is clicked (infoWindow.close()).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it within a geocoder callback function (a little different than the directionService, but still using a callback function, so the methodology should be the same) using only one infowindow. I would use this in a loop when geocoding a bunch of addresses.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': value}, function(results, status) {

  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

        //create and add marker to map based off geocode result
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
            map: map,
            title: results[0].formatted_address,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });

        //add marker to array so we can clear it later
        markersArray.push(marker); 

        //create listener for marker infowindow and set content
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
            infowindow.close();
            infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Casey. I know how to add listeners for 1 marker. The challenge is to do that for an _array_ of markers _outside_ the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is have an external function that sets the content on the infowindow, and as you add your markers, you call that function instead of having the event listener declared inline within your loop.  The problem is that after all the markers are created, when you click one, it will just use whatever the value of results[0].formatted_address is, which is whatever it was last set to at the end of the loop.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    title: address['title']
});
//push the marker to a list of markers attached to the map
//this can be useful to delete all markers in a later step
map.markers.push(marker);

// add an event listener for this marker
bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, address['title']);
```

And that function is simply:

```
function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, html) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(html);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

PS: You shouldn't need to call infowindow.close() prior to calling infowindow.open().  As there's only one infowindow, the API will automatically close it before reopening it at the new location.

Comment: Thanks Duncan. The problem I have is that I need to set a description for each marker inside a callback function, so that later on I could use that description to show different text for each marker's InfoWindow..